# Fixed and fluid columns

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a full width webpage, that when the browser scales down from a large display to medium, a sidebar collapses, then when the display is the width of the main content, the sidebar drops below the content (I'll explain with pictures).

I've created this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/2/

In it there is a fixed sidebar - the main navigation.
Also there is the `div.inside` which holds all the content.
`<article class="one">` holds the main content (the news article), while `<article class="two">` will hold related posts, adverts, and the like.

What I intend to create is (excuse the fiddle not being large enough to show this):

- The `header` remains the same size.
- The `<article class="one">` will have a width of 920px, or 46em (on a base 20px). It will remain this width until the browser window is 46em or less.
- The `<article class="two">` will fill up the remainder of the browser next to `<article class="one">`. When the width of `<article class="two">` reaches a certain width it will drop the content into one column. Then when the width is 46em, it will drop below the content.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest googling 'responsive web design' and learn the basics of how media queries etc work

Comment: @JamesKing I know how to use "responsive web design". You probably weren't intending to sound snarky, but it was. Have a look at my answer to see how I ended up doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update to my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/6/

After some tinkering, it got there.

Then when the images drop to the right side, under the main text I'll use the `media-query` to remove the `margins`

Answer (score 1):

[Check Bootstrap 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com), it provides everything you're looking for!

as an example: in this case your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id='text' class='col-lg-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12'>
   put your text here
</div>
<div id='images' class='col-lg-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
   <div id='img1' class='col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6'> ... </div>
   <div id='img1' class='col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6'> ... </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid. For different screen sized (LG, SM, XS for instance) you can define how many of these columns a DIV takes up in that grid.

Comment: To be honest, not a fan of the Bootstrap. I think it's one of those "grown up without it, never needed it" kind of things. I ended up figuring it out though.

Comment: you can always just grab the scaling part they use and 'nick' that for your own use... @media(max-width:700px){.inside{width:200px;float:left;whaterever...}}.

Comment: I did use @media at breakpoints to close down the images, expand their width, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Like people above said , try instead using bootstrap framework.

However if you don't want that then just read about media queries.
You can start here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I was intending to use media queries to drop the sidebar down, when needed. Have a look at my answer to see how I ended up fixing it :)

Answer (score 0):

`<edit>` You could use `float` as a fallback for the `flexbox` http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/8/ `</edit>`

---

If you do not mind using `flexbox` , *for younger browser only*, you could give it a try :
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/4/)**

```
.inside, article.two{
    display:flex;
    padding:1em;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.inside, article {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin:1em;
}
article.one {
    flex:3;
    min-width:800px;
}
article.two {
min-width:200px;
}
.filler {
    min-width:200px;
    min-height:80px;
    margin:auto;
    background:black;
    margin:1em;
    align-self:flex-start;
    flex:1;
}
```

---

check it in different browser to find out if it suits your needs.

bootstrap can be used as a fallback for browser wich doesn't apply the flex rules.

Comment: I thought about flex box but IE is my main concern. If it went back to IE8 (thats the lowest we go) then I'd be right on it.

Comment: Then , you have just the floatting and layout left to help you  http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/7/

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv A mixed of float and flex , float will be a fallback. http://jsfiddle.net/7N2Jr/8/